# Prove that if $A, B$ (both $n\times n$ matrix) are similar, then Null($A$)$=$Null($B$).

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that if $A,B$ (both $n\times n$ matrix) are similar, then Null($A$)$=$Null($B$).

Defn: If $A,B$ (both $n\times n$ matrix) are similar, then there exists $P$ which is a $n\times n$ matrix such that $A=PBP^{-1}$.

I used the definition of similarity between matrices to first prove that Null($A$) is a subset of Null($B$).

If $x$ is an element of Null($A$),

$Ax=0$

$PBP^{-1}x=0$

I need to show that $x$ is an element of Null($B$), but I’m not sure how to.

Comment: What is meant by $N(A)$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson N(A) means the null space of matrix A.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Show your efforts so far please and say where this question came from. -1 and Vote-To-Close

Comment: @Mike I’m sorry. I have corrected my post. Can you take a look at it?

Comment: @Theo, I think you're working too hard. Let $A$ be any singular non-symmetric $2\times2$, and let $B$ be the transpose of $A$. They're guaranteed to be similar, no need to compute $P$.

Comment: I suspect that $\text{Null}(A)$ is the nullity, i.e. the dimension of the null space, rather than the null space itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually false. The counter example could be : matrix A is\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}

For any other invertible matrices P, example \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}
$P^{-1}$ is \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1/2\end{bmatrix}

And by the similarity, A=PB$P^{-1}$, you can get B=$P^{-1}$AP which is \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&0\end{bmatrix}
Then, Null(A)=$ span(\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\end{bmatrix} )$ which is different from null space of B so the statement is false.

Comment: There's no need to calculate $P$ or $PBP^{-1}$. Just let $B$ be the transpose of $A$; then $A$ and $B$ are similar, but don't have the same nullspace.